# How can I insert number of lines in between the .txt file and move or append its data below that inserted lines using python?

Tags: python

my `.txt` file is below

```
Pyhton is open source language
its a freeware
it has lot of in built modules
python is easiest
```

what should I do to insert two lines below `its freeware` lines and move the remaining data below that inserted lines, as shown below,

```
Pyhton is open source language
its a freeware
Hi
my name is shubham
it has lot of in bult modules
python is easiest
```

I have tried following code
but its appending the new lines at last in file

```
file_to_write = r"file.txt"
with open(file_to_write,'a') as fw:
    fw.write('Hi\n')
    fw.write('my name is shubham')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a new line add `\n` before where you wish to add a new line within the string.

`\n`  = move to next line, so if you need to move it down further just add more `\n`, for example:

`\n\n` = move 2 lines below.

EXAMPLE.

```
text = "Python is an open source language. \nits a freeware \n\nHi my name is shubham. it has lot of in built modules python is easiest"

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

**Notice** how i have enclosed all the text in one variable, and whereever I needed to insert a new line (or several new lines), I have included, 1 or more `\n` before the text.

Now that all the info is stored within the single variable **text**, I am now able to simply pass the **text** variable as a **parameter** for the **write function** and have it all appropriately save in the **test.txt** file.

Comment: as you said '\n' adds new line yes, but i need to insert new two lines in between file not at the end of file like append

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example, please let me know if that is the solution you seek. Sorry if I am misunderstanding what you want to do.